# How to add Burmese language in Android app

Tags: android, multilingual

I want to make an app in English and Burmese language. I create a "values-my-rMM" folder and place string.xml file for Burmese support.

I am using this code in onCreate()

```
Locale myLocale = new Locale("my-rMM");     
        Resources res = getResources(); 
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics(); 
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration(); 
        conf.locale = myLocale; 
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

this code work perfectly for Spanish, French etc. but it's not working for Burmese language. I also tested on android 5.0.1 but nothing is working.

Comment: I think that language should be installed in your mobile, and then you can set that language. for example see  http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-building-multi-language-supported-app/

Comment: i am testing on Nexus 5 and it has Burmese language..